# cant compile any cursor example

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make any cursor example  working, but just cant make it happen.
IDE: Oracle SQL developer
database: 10g sql oracle

I've tried this three examples, but it didn't compile well. Can someone provide me with working examples? 

 First one:
EDIT: works! just had 'where where'

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR person_data_cur
   as
      SELECT *
        FROM personal_data
       WHERE  where name='Karol';
BEGIN
   FOR person_data
   IN person_data_cur
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         person_data.surname);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

and this:

```
DECLARE my_cursor1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT  name, surname
    FROM personal_data
    WHERE name='Karol';
```

^error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: row 1, column 27:
PLS-00103: found symbol "FOR" when expected one of following:

   := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

or even this: 
EDIT: this one is OK, just my IDE ignored first two lines, and executed others... but i guess it was OK since it wasnt inside any block or procedure

```
CURSOR c1
IS
  SELECT course_number
  FROM courses_tbl
  WHERE course_name = name_in;
```

Comment: oh silly me  i had WHERE WHERE at line 6 example1--->works.... :D 

but still  not sure how to do other 2 examples

Comment: It would be easier if you posted the errors as well.

Comment: You have 3 cursor declarations - one of them works, two don't. So how about checking where the definition of the other two differs? (Hint: `FOR` and `IS`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Second Example : Your syntax is incorrect.
The pseudo code for the cursor is :

```
        Declare
             Cursor Cursor_name
             is
               select * from table where <Conditions>;
          Begin
            For cur_Rec in cursor_name
               Loop
                   <what you want to do>

               End Loop;
          End;
```

For the third example, I believe `name_in` is an input parameter, please correct the syntax to :

```
      CURSOR c1 (name_in VARCHAR2)
      IS
        SELECT course_number
        FROM courses_tbl
        WHERE course_name = name_in;
```

Please refer [Cursor Declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/cursor_declaration.htm#i33637) for more details